# How to set custom textStyle in a class?

Tags: android, styles

I am creating a class and set Text Style. I have already defined in attrs and styleable and style and make getter setter and set textStyle bold still text is not getting bold. How to set bold text? Plz help?

```
 <declare-styleable name="CustomTagGroup"> 
        <attr name="descriptionTextStyle" format="flags">
            <flag name="normal" value="0" />
            <flag name="bold" value="1" />
            <flag name="italic" value="2" />
            <flag name="bolditalic" value="3" />
        </attr>

    <style name="CustomTagGroup">
  <item name="atg_horizontalPadding">12dp</item>
        <item name="atg_verticalPadding">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="descriptionTextStyle">bolditalic</item>
    </style>
```

---

```
  final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTagGroup, defStyleAttr, R.style.CustomTagGroup);
        try {
a.getType(R.styleable.CustomTagGroup_descriptionTextStyle);
            int bold = Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC;
            textStyle = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomTagGroup_descriptionTextStyle, bold);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your custom class that extends **TextView**?
If yes then first get attribute taht you define in your xml like:

```
<com.package.CustomTextView
 ......
 app:text_style = "1"
/>
```

After taking attribute value the add setBold by below code

```
@Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // set your if else condition that come from attr
        // Like you get 1 then execute below line
        this.setTypeface(getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
    }
```

Comment: My Custom Class extends ViewGroup.

Please suggest another method as it is not working for me.